# Is it possible to pass data using Mapper?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, clean-architecture

I am studying `Clean Architecture` and `MVVM`. But it is very difficult and I have a question.

There are two `fragments`, `A` and `B`.

Both `A` and `B` use the `MVVM pattern`, so they have a `ViewModel` and a `Repository`.

The `Repository` belongs to the `Data layer`.

`B`'s repo does not store or load data in Local(DB) and Remote(server).

It just creates and deletes `SetInfo` data.
(`SetInfo` is a model class for the `Domain layer`).

I want to send the generated data to `A` Fragment.

My question here is how can I send the data of the `domain layer` to `A`? The Domain layer is pure Kotlin, so you can't even use `Parcelable`.

The answer to a [similar question](https://github.com/antoniolg/clean-architecture/issues/1) tells me to create a Model class in Presentation and use Data Mapper, but how can you pass data with this?

I've looked at other `Mapper` codes, but I can't quite figure it out.

please help me.

---

**Domain Layer**

```
data class SetInfo(
    val set: Int,
    var weight: String = "",
    var reps: String = "",
    var unit: WorkoutUnit = WorkoutUnit.kg,
)
```

**Data layer**

```
class BRepository() {
    private var setInfoList = ArrayList<SetInfo>()

    fun addSet() {
        setInfoList.let { list ->
            val item = SetInfo(set = setInfoList.size + 1)
            list.add(item)
        }
    }

    fun deleteSet() {
        if(setInfoList.size != 0) {
            setInfoList.let { list ->
                list.removeLast()
            }
        }
        return
    }
}
```

**Data Layer**

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Workout::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("workoutId"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("parentWorkoutId"), 
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE 
        )
    ]
)
data class SetInfoEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val set: Int,
    var weight: String = "", 
    var reps: String = "",
    var unit: WorkoutUnit = WorkoutUnit.kg,
    val parentWorkoutId: Long = 0
)
```

---

**UPDATE**

**Presentation Layer**

B Fragment

```
// Passing data from Fragment B to Fragment A using safeargs in Navigation Component.

class BFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentBBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

            save.setOnClickListener {
                val uiModel : SetInfoUiModel = vm.getData() // vm is viewmodel
                BFragmentDirections.actionBFragmenttoAFragment(uiModel)
            }
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

A Fragment

```
// Receives data received from B and transfers it to A Repo (to store the MVVM pattern and DB)
class AFragment : Fragment() {
    private val args: AFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    private lateinit vm: AViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentABinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val setInfoUiModel = args.uiModel
        vm = AViewModel(setInfoUiModel) // Passing to A repo via viewmodel

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

BViewModel

```
class BViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val repository: BRepository = BRepository()
    
    fun getData() = repository.getData()
}
```

AViewModel

```
class AViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val repository: ARepository = ARepository()

    fun save(data: SetInfoUiModel) {
        repository.save(data)
    }
}
```

**Domain Layer**

SetInfo

```
data class SetInfo(
    ... // properties
)
```

**Data Layer**

SetInfoUiModel

```
@Parcelize
data class SetInfoUiModel(
  ... // properties
): Parcelable
```

B Repository

```
class BRepository() {
    private var setInfo = SetInfo()

    ... // etc code


    fun SetInfo.toUiModel() = SetInfoUiModel(...)

    fun getData() = setInfo.toUiModel(...)
}
```

A Repository

```
class ARepository() {
    private lateinit var setInfoUiModel : SetInfoUiModel


    // Data of B Fragment passed from A viewmodel.
    fun save(data : SetInfoUiModel) {
        setInfo = data
        ... // save DB
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to send an object of type `SetInfo` from fragment B to fragment A?

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, to pass an object between fragments, the class must be made `Parcelable`, but `SetInfo` is against the architecture because it is a `domain layer`. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Fragment A has no access to the source of truth (the repository) for the `SetInfo` object that it needs and it can get that only from fragment B,

You will have to create a new parcelable model in your UI layer and a corresponding mapper for that too.

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class SetInfoUiModel(
    val set: Int,
    var weight: String = "",
    var reps: String = "",
    var unit: WorkoutUnit = WorkoutUnit.kg,    // I assume this WorkoutUnit is some Parcelable data type
): Parcelable

fun SetInfo.toUiModel() = SetInfoUiModel(set, weight, reps, unit)
```

Now, instead of using `SetInfo`, you should be using `SetInfoUiModel` everywhere in the UI layer. Whenever you want to convert a `SetInfo` to `SetInfoUiModel` you can easily do that with the mapper and because it's parcelable you can send it from one fragment to other.

(Also, I suggest using all `val`s in data models whenever possible. It's almost always helpful and can help you avoid bugs at a lot of places)

Comment: Should the `SetInfoUiModel` be placed in the `UI Layer` (probably the `Presentation layer package`)? Or should it be located in the `Data Layer(package)`?

Comment: In the UI Layer

Comment: Okay.. Then `toUiModel()` is used first in the `B repo`, right?

Instead of using `toUiModel()` after sending `setInfoList` to `fragment A`, is it correct to use `toUiModel()` in repo `B` to change to `SetInfoEntity` type and send to `fragment A`?

Comment: No, `toUiModel()` will also be called in the UI Layer because the data layer doesn't know about `SetInfoUiModel`. After to get `SetInfo` from repo, you can call `toUiModel` on it and use `SetInfoUiModel` everywhere in the UI layer.

Comment: I wrote the code really simply.. (Please see the updated code) Isn't that what it should be like..?

Comment: Yeah, you can do this too. Since `data` is an android module, you use `Parcelable`s there. I was just saying that Parcelables only make sense in the UI Layer. So the other option you had was to use `fun getData() = repository.getData().toUiModel()` in `BViewModel` and `repository.save(data.toDomainModel())` in `AViewModel`. This would have required one more mapper though.

Comment: But you said `toUiModel()` is called from the `UI layer (like ViewModel)`.

But in the code I updated, `toUiModel()` is called in the `repo`.

Although, of course, I am calling `getData()` from the `ViewModel`.